# Detecting the previous item in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a model class called (messages). In on bind view holder method of recycler view adapter I do this to extract the (time) string from the (messages) class:

```
@override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHodler view holder, int position){

  //here I extract the time value from (messages) class

  messages mess=messageslist.get(position);

  //I store it in a long variable called time

  long time= mess.getTime();


 }
```

Until here I am only getting the time value of each item in recycler view. But I want also to get the time of the previous item and compare it to the next one.

**In other words I am trying to find the difference of time between each 2 items in recyclerview.**

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

okay what I want to do is to show or hide a date view if the difference of date between the 2 items reached or passed 1 day. If I do it according to the answers below I get no results...like this

```
    //the time of the item
    long time= mess.getTime();

     //the time of the previous item according to the answers below

    long pre_time=messageslist.get(position-1).getTime();


     //now I compare the difference 


      if(time - pre_time >= 24*3600*1000){ 

         //show date
       }else{
         //hide date
        }
```

but doest work.

Comment: Maybe if(position > 0) { ... messageslist.get(position - 1); } ?

Comment: how are you setting the time ?

Comment: @SumitAnantwar I used date format to convert the long into date as day/month/year....the problem is just when to show the date view which is just a TextView.

Comment: @SumitAnantwar my problem is not by converting the millisecond long to date ...my problem is in showing the view when the difference of time between 2 messages pass the day. So that users know which group of messages  correspond to what date.

Comment: `(time - pre_time >= 24*3600*1000) ` will check if there is a difference of 24 hours between the two consecutive messages. This would be true only if the user has not sent any message for more than 24 hours.

Comment: @SumitAnantwar Can you please suggest a condition that works.

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited the answer based on updated question**

You should convert the time milliseconds to DAY_OF_MONTH and check if the day of the current item is greater than the day of the previous item.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

Messages mess = messagesList.get(position);
calendar.setTimeInMillis(mess.getTime());
int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

if (position > 0) {
    Messages previousMessage = messagesList.get(position - 1);
    if (previousMessage != null) {
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(previousMessage.getTime());
        int prevDate = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        if (date > prevDate) {
            // This is a different day than the previous message, so show the Date
        } else {
            // Same day, so hide the Date
        }

    }
} else {
    // This is the first message, so show the date
}
```

Comment: I want to know when to show a date above a new message group...any thoughts? thanks.

Comment: What are your criteria for showing the date? If you observe chat apps like Slack or Skype, as per my observation they generally group the messages per 5 mins interval.

Comment: I am trying to do like most common as per day.

Comment: If you are grouping per day, then you have to just check if the Date of the current item is greater than the date of the previous item, if `true` display the date. Please correct me if I did not understand your use case.

Comment: please check my EDIT I explained my problem more.

Comment: thanks this is the correct way to check, thanks for all the time and effort.

Comment: @Sumit @svi.data if a user adds message every day, consider this scenario, if `date`  = 2nd of month and for previous days messages `prevDate` = 1st then when `date` = 1st of a month and for previous days messages `prevDate` = 31st or 30th of previous month, then the condition `if (date > prevDate) {}` fails as 1 > 31 is false. You might want to use `if(date != prevDate)`

Answer (score 1):

```
messages mess = messageslist.get(position);
if (position > 0){
    long time_diffrence = mess.getTime() - messageslist.get(position-1).getTime();
}
```

Comment: I have a question, if I want  to check if the time between the 2 messages to know where to show the date above the message that states that a new chat group happend ....then how does your code help? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Step one timestamp to Date convert menthod

```
private String getDate(String createdDate) {
    long timestampString = Long.parseLong(createdDate);
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String value = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").
            format(new java.util.Date(timestampString * 1000));
    return value;
}
```

(2) Step two in onBindViewHolder

```
    if (position == 0) {
        holder.mTextViewNewTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mTextViewNewTime.setText(getDate(bean.getCreatedDate()));
    } else {
        String prev_date_time = getDate(mPojoTicketChatList.get(position - 1).getCreatedDate());
        //String prev_date[] = prev_date_time[0].split("-");
        if (getDate(bean.getCreatedDate()).equals(prev_date_time)) {
            holder.mTextViewNewTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.mTextViewNewTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mTextViewNewTime.setText(getDate(bean.getCreatedDate()));
        }
    }
```

Try it working for me